# Vue.JS waiting for a for loop to finish in watched property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

my application needs to make multiple API calls, in a certain order.

allMeetings should execute first, then pastMeetingsUUIDs second. What I am trying to do is make sure that the for-loop inside allMeetings completes first, before pastMeetingsUUIDs from firing (to ensure excessive API calls are not made.

At the moment, as I think it is meant to, the watched function pastMeetingUUID fires every time the pastMeetingUUIDs is updated. I want it to only fire once, after the forloop has completed.

```
watch: {

  allMeetings: function (){
    for (var i = 0; i <this.flatAllMeetings.length; i++){
         getPastMeetingUUIDByID(this.flatAllMeetings[i].id).then( data=> this.pastMeetingUUIDs.push(data.data))
       }
     this.allMeetingStatus = true
     }

  },

   pastMeetingUUIDs: function () {
   if(this.allMeetingStatus == true){

 //response is a mixed object array
      const entries = Object.entries(this.pastMeetingUUIDs)
      entries.forEach(element => {

        element[1].meetings.forEach(element =>{
            getPastMeetingParticipants(element.uuid).then(data=> console.log(data))
        })
      })
   }
}
 },
```

This currently will still loop through the pastMeetingsUUID array n times, I'm not sure why it would do that

Comment: I think it would be far more easier to chain the http calls than to try to synchronise them with watchers.

Comment: How would I go about that, every time I try getPastMeetingUUIDByID(this.flatAllMeetings[i].id).then( data=> this.pastMeetingUUIDs.push(data.data)).then(console.log(self.pastMeetingsUUIDs[n]) it returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
allMeetings: async function (){
    const meetingsUUIDs = []
    for (var i = 0; i <this.flatAllMeetings.length; i++) {
       const result = await getPastMeetingUUIDByID(this.flatAllMeetings[i].id)
       meetingsUUIDs.push(result.data)
    }
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this.pastMeetingUUIDs, meetingsUUIDs);
    this.allMeetingStatus = true
}
```

Comment: Adding async didn't work, the function never returned any values to this.pastMeetingsUUIDs, and the for loop never runs.

Comment: If this.flatAllMeetings.length > 0 then at least one iteration of a for-loop takes place. Place console.log('something)' to make sure for-loop is started and finished

Comment: I did, it does not run at all.

Comment: So you are saying that a watch on allMeetings did not call al all?

Comment: Yeah, Im really new to javascript, and Im struggling to get my head around this stuff, and async functions. 

So I have a response from an API which is an array of objects. I want to call a second request based off information returned from the first, hence me watching to see if the variables changed before trying to send off a second.

Comment: maybe you don't need these watches? I can't recommend if I don;t know what you try to achieve